# How to pass parameter in URL body using typescript for rest API (ionic)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and typescript.I have an api. I can access the api using post method only and parameter passed in body for security purposes. I want json data using these api. but i don't have any idea for passing the parameter in body

I attached my coding that i tried

**sample.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage,  NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HttpProvider} from '../../providers/http/http';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TraineristorePage } from '../traineristore/traineristore';
import { StorePage } from '../store/store';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/http';
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-sample',
    templateUrl: 'sample.html',
    providers:[HttpProvider]
})
export class SamplePage {
    users: any;
    headers:Headers;
    options:RequestOptions;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loadingCtrl: 
            LoadingController, public navParams: NavParams, private  
            httpProvider:HttpProvider, public http:Http) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SamplePage');
}

loadJson(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
    charset=UTF-8');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let data="token="+""+
    "&searchvalue="+""+
    "&sortby="+""+
    "&sorttype="+""+
    "&filter="+""+
    "&startfrom="+""+
    "&limit="+""+
    "&producttype=1";

    this.http.post('this is my API URL', data,  options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.users = res.data;
            console.log(this.users);
        },
        (err) => {
            alert("failed to load json data");
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my ionic html 
**sample.html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="loadJson()">Load Data</button>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="col" *ngFor="let user of users" >
        <p class="t"> {{user.productid}}</p>
        <ion-icon class="icon" name="ios-heart-outline" md="md-heart"></ion-icon>
        <br>
        <p class="p">ProductId : {{user.name}}</p>
        <!--<img class="img" src="{{user.productImg}}" width="97px" 
        height="86px" ng-click="nextpage()">&emsp;

        <p class="p">Rs {{user.price}}</p>
        --><hr>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Please give me some suggestions or ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of js you straightly call the API in ionic

```
var link = "Your API";
  var body = JSON.stringify({mno: mobile,pwd: password});

  return new Promise(resolve=>{
        this.http
        .post(link,body)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe((data : any) =>
        {

          this.items = data;
          console.log(this.items);


        },
        (error : any) =>
        {
           console.dir(error);

        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just include js in ionic to achieve the body parameter in url

```
 sup(){
 $.post("http:xxxxxxxxxx/"+"listProducts",
      {  
 "token" : ''  ,
 "searchvalue" : '' , //Product Name
 "sortby" : '' , //Brand
  "sorttype" : '' , //asc,desc
  "filter" : '' , //Category
  "startfrom" : '' , //1,2, etc
  "limit" : '',  //1,10,4,5, etc
   "producttype" : '1'  //1 Suppliments or 2 accessories
     }, 
      function(data,status){
      var d = JSON.parse(data);
     }
 }
```

this code is successfully retrieve the JSON data from API
I hope this is useful to someone else
Thank You